# How to register listeners in android

Tags: android

I have an Activity_X which when does some action must notify Activity_A to change its ListItems etc..,

**I tried:**

```
public interface NewItemListener {

    public void onNewItem (int id, int count);
}

public class Activity_X extends SherlockFragmentActivity {

    private NewItemListener NIL;
    public void setNewItemListener(NewItemListener listen) {

        NIL = listen;
    }
    public void onSomeAction {

       NIL.onNewItem(10, 20);
    }
}

public class Activity_A extends SherlockFragmentActivity implements NewItemListener{

    onCreate(){
        Activity_X Ax = new Activity_X();
        Ax.setNewItemListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onNewItem(int id, int count) {

        Log.d("id = " + id, "count = " + count);
    }
}
```

But nothing seems to work.

Thank You

Comment: You have not called the function "onSomeAction()" anywhere in the Activity_X.

Answer (score 1):

You have not understand the android concept at all.

There is always only one Activity at once visible.

Therefore your code will not work. You can not instantiate a Activity by calling new Activity_X();

The Android OS is responsible to start / instantiate an Activity, and an Activity has its lifecycle (onCreate(), onResume(), onPause() onDestroy()) but you can not instantiate Activities directly like you would do, and as mentioned before, there is normally only one active Activity on screen (The only way you can have two activities active at the same time is, if you have a activity with transparent background on top of a normal activity).

Read that:
[Android getting started](http://developer.android.com/training/index.html)

Comment: Yeah that's fine. So, how exactly can I use callbacks in android between Activities other than `onActivityResult`.

Comment: To share data between Avtivities you must use onActivityResult() and Intent ... Or you may consider to use Fragments... Activity is the parent of a fragment. The Activity can be a Listener on a Fragment. By doing something on a Fragment can notify the Activity, since the Activity can be a listener. Than the activity can do something useful within this callback (like replacing the current fragment with another fragment). But implementing a listener between activities is not possible. The only way to do that is to use onActivityResult()

Comment: SharedPrefrences, should be like the name suggests, only be used to store the users prefrences settings and not as some kind of database to write and read data ... So you would better say: You can try a Database. But that is still not something like a listener! In fact its an Anti-Pattern, as well as store the data in some kind of singleton. If you want to share data between activies use onActivityResult() and Intents!

Answer (score 0):

For communication between activities you should use an [Intent](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html).

An other way to share "information" is to use a threads in your activities and send messages see : [Handler](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html)

I hope this helps